# How to validate a datagridview column with 3 database field combine together

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, validation, datagridview

Basically I have a datagridview which I retrieve from database and 3 of the database field column I combine into a column in datagridview.

But now the problem come, I need to do update but before that I need to validate what the user have editing before click on the update button, but I don't know how to validate them when they are in the same column in the datagridview.

I am able to validate a column with only one database field

p.s I am doing editing and updating in the datagridview, I need to validate that 3 database field column.

This is how I call my databasase into the datagridview

ps. the position is int

```
protected void BindStaff()
{
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BRandCom;Integrated Security=True");
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StaffID, (StaffName+','+ StaffNRIC+','+ Position + ';')as StaffDetail, yearIn, age, address, email, stayIndicator FROM StaffBook", conn);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(ds);
  DGVStaffBook.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

this is the column i am saying i am able to validate (only one database field column)

```
private void DGVStaffBook_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
      {

        int stayInd;

       if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
          stayInd = Convert.ToInt32(DGVStaffBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);

          if (stayInd != 0 && stayInd != 1)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only 1 or 0");
            DGVStaffBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = DBNull.Value;
          }
          else
            return;

        }
      }

    }
```

i try this for position , but it give me error: input string was not correct format

```
  private void DGVStaffBook_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
            {

                             if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
                {
                    String[] position = null;
                    position = Convert.ToString(DGVStaffBook.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value).Split(',');

                    if (int.Parse(position[2]) != 1 && int.Parse(position[2])!=2 ) 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Update number type accordingly:" + Environment.NewLine + "1  - High rank only " + Environment.NewLine + "2  -Low Rank" );
                    }
                    else 
                        return;

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: How are you displaying it in the gridview, maybe you can validate based on separators, If you are not able to identify the changes how would the gridview be able to do so

Comment: the select 3 database column field i name in as staffdetail, so in datagridview, the datapropertyname i put as staff detail...
what do you mean by a separators??

Comment: @V4Vendetta can show me, it will be nice...wont be so confuse of what you saying, oh ya,forgot to mention i the position is in int

Comment: Something like `|` or `,` to distinguish the fields but anyway you will have to maintain them separately else it would be a confusing while updates and inserts

Comment: @V4Vendetta you  mean like split? cause i got a requirement saying that they got to be together, can show me how to validate it... esp the NRIC, how to validate it in the datagridview...really need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO displaying 3 database fields and allowing the user to edit the same in one column is dangerous. **Suggest you to show them as 3 separate columns instead.**

Maybe you can also try by making the 3 corresponding properties and merge them via a separator like `|` which would not occur in your fields via a fourth property. Now when you get the value split the same on `|` and perform your checks and also assign back those respective values to the 3 corresponding properties. (But i wouldn't recommend this)
`Field1` `Field2` `Field3`

`StaffDetails` -- `Field1`+"|" +`Field2`+"|" + `Field3`

Then use e.FormattedValue.ToString() and split this on `|`to get string[] of 3 ,now validate

Also you can take a look on creating a Column of `MaskedTextBox` this will also help but the User experience is gonna be pathetic

Comment: @V4Vendetta, you see my retrieve code, i did separate it by comma " , "....bt how to get them out...can do the validating NRIC and show me how, which i think i will be able to do the rest.......please

Comment: @V4Vendetta...i try something ...help me see why gt the error....i edited in my question

Comment: I think it has an invalid string and unable to convert it to int, what is the value you have , also check out using `int.TryParse`

Comment: position is a varchar(max), when it have value of 1 or 2...at where?can show me how to change...in your way

Comment: I am asking while you debug what do you see as value of `position[2]`

Comment: so you better remove `;` from the query

Comment: but i need to need to use in later on, so in the retrieve i cant remove...if there a way to avoid it taking this ;

Comment: @V4Vendetta..i figure out why got error...but can teach me how to validate NRIC...NRIC is like eg S1234567H...so bascially is the front must a be a S character and the middle is a 7 Numerical digit and the last one is any alpabet

Comment: so you know how to validate NRIC in the datagridview...in the combine one column????

Comment: These is deviating from the question you asked and venturing into different avenues, ask a different precise question